# setTimeout on promises inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, promise

What I want to do is this:

Loop over a collection of data, for each data element make a call to an API, wait that the promise fail or resolve, pause for 30sec... then do this again for the next data element until there is nothing to iterate over in the collection ... finally display a 'done' message.

So far this is the code I wrote, gathering ideas in other SO questions, and this is not working the way I'd like.

```
populateDB();

// these 2 helper functions were found on SO

function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function sleep(fn, ...args) {
  await timeout(30000);
  return fn(...args);
}

// this is the main function that makes the api calls
function populateDB() {

  for (let stock of universe.universe) {
    sleep(() => {
      // actual API call
      return alpha.data
        .daily(stock)
        .then(data => {
          // write data to the db when promise resolves
          db.get("stocks")
            .push({ [stock]: polishData(data) })
            .write();
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    });
  }

  console.log("Done!");
}
```

All the promised are still chaining one after another there is no pause. I don't think I understand Promises enough to debug this... what would be the code that works the way I'd like it to ?

Comment: `async function populateDB` and  `await sleep(() => {`

Comment: thanks a lot that was it @JaromandaX. Wanna write an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) in your `populateDB` function:

```
async function populateDB() {

  for (let stock of universe.universe) {
    await sleep(() => {
      // actual API call
      return alpha.data
        .daily(stock)
        .then(data => {
          // write data to the db when promise resolves
          db.get("stocks")
            .push({ [stock]: polishData(data) })
            .write();
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    });
  }
  console.log("Done!");
}
```