# How to count number using promise

Tags: javascript

I want to counter some number using promise that the result is 1,2,3,done and I have coded it like this

```js
const state = true

const count = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (state) {
    resolve("counter work")
    for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(i);
      }, 1000);
    }
    console.log("done");
  } else {
    reject("counter not work")
  }
})
count
  .then((response) => console.log("success", response))
  .catch((response) => console.log("failed", response));
```

and the result is : done,1,2,3 but i want the result 1,2,3,done

can anybody tell why my code have result like that and how the code should it is

Comment: `resolve` will immediately call the `.then`. You need to call it only after the third `setTimeout` fires

Comment: First learn the basic about what is Promise [https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp)

Comment: Look up how `setTimeout` works, too. Since you're calling it in a loop, you'd start three timeouts right away that will all run a second later.

Comment: Second learn about the order of operation of using timouts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setTimeout on promises inside a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55437775/settimeout-on-promises-inside-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

The early resolve aside, the reason for "done" being logged first is that you're calling `setTimeout` in a loop. `setTimeout` doesn't block execution, it queues a callback to be run after some time and returns immediately.
So you're just creating three Timeouts that'll all fire about a second after you've exited the loop and logged "done".

To create a timer, you could conditionally call `setTimeout` within the callback:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let i = 0
  function increment () {
    i++
    console.log(i)
    if (i < 3) {
      setTimeout(increment, 1000)
    } else {
      console.log('done')
      resolve() // to mark the promise as completed
    }
  }
  setTimeout(increment, 1000)
})
```